# Diophantus math

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history

Find two numbers such that their difference and also the difference of their cubes are given numbers; say, their difference is 6 and the difference of their cubes are 504.  Call the numbers $x + 3$ and $x - 3$.

Comment: I got x to be the sqaure root of 28... the book says the answer answer is 8 and 2 respectively.  not sure if I did wrong math or what

Comment: from what I am seeing exactly 8 and 2 do not satisfy the equation... so maybe the book was just rounding up?

Comment: My calculator says $(\sqrt{28}+3)^3 - (\sqrt{28}-3)^3 = 558$, not $504$.

Comment: I think the book means that $x = 5$ satisfies the equation you are supposed to derive for $x$, giving the pair of numbers $5+3=8$ and $5-3=2$ as a solution to the original problem.  There should be no rounding here, because Diophantine problems deal with exact integer solutions.

Comment: sorry simple math error.  x=5 so the values are 8 and 2

Answer (score 2):

Well, using the difference of cubes formula $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2),$ we get $$\begin{align}504 &= (x+3)^3-(x-3)^3\\ &= \bigl((x+3)-(x-3)\bigr)\left((x+3)^2+(x+3)(x-3)+(x-3)^2\right)\\ &= 6\bigl((x^2+6x+9)+(x^2-9)+(x^2-6x+9)\bigr)\\ &= 6(3x^2+9)\\ &= 18x^2+54.\end{align}$$ You can take it from there, yes?